# Bind9's working only locally

Tags: networking, apache2, dns

I'm trying to make multi sites with apache2, but I need domains to ping it, therefore I'm trying to host dns with Bind9.

The problom is that the dns are pinging only locallly!
Why?

If someone knowns to resolve this issue, please tell me!

This is my named.conf.option:
`options {
directory "/var/cache/bind";

```
    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    forwarders {
            1.2.3.4;
            5.6.7.8;
    };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation no;

    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    listen-on { any; };
    allow-query-cache { any; };

    acl trusted {
            192.168.1.0/24;  // Local network
            10.0.0.0/8;     // Another local network
    };

    allow-query { trusted; };
```

};
`

Resolve.conf:
`nameserver 185.229.236.154 search rewardads.net domain rewardads.net`

db.rewardads.net:
`$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     dns.rewardads.com. root.dns.rewardads.net. (
2023110901 ; Serial
3600       ; Refresh
1800       ; Retry
604800     ; Expire
86400 )    ; Minimum TTL

```
    IN      NS      dns.rewardsads.net.
```

dns     IN      A       185.229.236.154`

Comment: What does this mean? ***The problem is that the dns are pinging only locally!***. Edit your post and Cleary define what you are trying to do. Then describe in detail what does not work. Vague descriptions are not helpful. If your goal is to have the Internet query your name server, that is not going to happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.